# Evaluating $\int \frac{dx}{x^2-1}$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

In Wolfram alpha I computed the  following integral, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%28x%5E2-1%29+).
Although, I expected to get
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{x-1}{x+1}+c$$
instead of
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{1-x}{x+1}+c$$
As a result of the previous when someone computes
$$\int_{2}^{3}\frac{dx}{x^2-1}$$
gets the following (in Wolfram alpha) : $\tanh^{-1}(2) - \tanh^{-1}(3)$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}{\ln\frac{3}{2}}.$ However if you "click" over the answer $\tanh^{-1}(2) - \tanh^{-1}(3)$  you will get as an alternative form the answer $\frac{1}{2}{\ln\frac{3}{2}}.$ All other systems I tried, always provide $\frac{1}{2}{\ln\frac{3}{2}}$ as an answer. I can't see the point why Wolfram alpha provides such an answer for such a simple and straightforward integral.

On the other hand, Wolfram alpha writes that it assumes : *a complex valued logarithm*. Why? How can I tell not to assume that?

Comment: MMA by default assumes complex variables and the Log is a multivalued function. If you specify  `x>0` you will get your answer

Comment: OK. This does not make sense to me, since I wrote that x is $2\leq x\leq 3.$ I have to further write $x>0?$ I am not very familiar with mathematica...Also. how can I write this in Wolfram alpha?

Comment: Related: [(235904)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/235904)

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. It makes it easier to search for Q&A, too. You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful.

Comment: `Integrate[1/(x^2 - 1), {x, 2, 3}] // TrigToExp // Simplify` gets the form you want.

Comment: The `ArcTanh` result follows simply from the derivative `D[ArcTanh[x], x]`. You wish to restrict the derivative formulas it is allowed to use for finding antiderivatives?

Comment: I expected to get the the following antiderivative , $\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{x-1}{x+1}.$ This agrees with the theory we usually  learn in calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From inside MMA you can reach WolframAlpha by:

[image]

Comment: Interesting that this gives $\log(1-x)$ instead of the $\log(x-1)$ desired by the OP. I guess they decided to accept the *Mathematica* result (W|A here is the same as `Integrate[1/(x^2 - 1), x]`).

Answer (score 2):

The two integrals are equal up to a constant:

```
f = 1/2 Log[(x - 1)/(x + 1)];
g = 1/2 Log[(1 - x)/(x + 1)];
D[f, x] - D[g, x] // Simplify
```

> 0

Comment: true. Both answers are right. I am not saying that mathematica answers wrong. But mathematica complicates things without reason. If someone, say a student, follows the methodology to compute this integral will end up with the $\frac{1}{2}\ln{(x-1)/(x+1)},$ so I found the specific answer confusing.

Comment: @111 (1) Cauchy, Riemann et al. with some effort gave the reason why Mathematica should do things this way, though I sometimes wish there were a built-in way to deal with different branches. (2) Even in an all-real example $\int \sin x \cos x \, dx$, a student will come up with one of three answers and sometimes think the other two are wrong, at least my students do (${1\over2}\sin^2x,\;-{1\over2}\cos^2x,\;-{1\over4}\cos2x$).

Comment: your answer (1) is very unclear  (at least to me). As far as (2), yes I angry with you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

For `2 <= x <= 3`

```
Assuming[2 <= x <= 3, Integrate[1/(x^2 - 1), x] // Simplify]

(* 1/2 Log[(1 - x)/(1 + x)] *)
```

For `x > 0`

```
Assuming[x > 0, Integrate[1/(x^2 - 1), x] // Simplify]

(* 1/2 Log[(1 - x)/(1 + x)] *)
```

For `x ∈ Reals`

```
Assuming[x ∈ Reals, Integrate[1/(x^2 - 1), x] // FullSimplify]

(* -ArcTanh[x] *)
```

For `x ∈ Complexes`

```
Integrate[1/(x^2 - 1), x] // FullSimplify

(* -ArcTanh[x] *)
```